# "the glacial pace at which justice has arrived"

Tags: prepositions

*Thursday’s verdict will be a reminder of the scale of the killings – some 100,000 people died in Bosnia alone, with other victims in Croatia and Kosovo – and of **the glacial pace at which justice has arrived**.*

Source: http://www.theguardian.com/world/2016/mar/22/the-hunt-for-radovan-karadzic-ruthless-warlord-turned-spiritual-healer

I have a question regarding the usage of the preposition "at" before "which justice". I pressume that the author wants to say it lasted very long time before justice has realized. But I do not understand why "glacial pace at which" is used. Glacial pace is something like extremely slow speed so I would use "glacial pace **by** which justice has arrived". In the original sentence it is suggested that glacial pace is some kind of a place. Can you explain to me what's wrong with my consideration?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

At first I was struggling with "arrive by" versus "arrive at" too. Then I realised "at" is not actually attached to "arrive" but rather to "pace".

English uses "at x pace" (like speed).

> At snail's pace
>
> At a rapid pace

So if we re-order the difficult part of the sentence we get:

> Justice has arrived **at [a] glacial pace**.

So, "at a glacial pace" works as an adverbial describing how justice arrived.

To reaffirm your understanding of "arrive by" and "arrive at", I think you have it quite nicely.

Arrive by (normally the means of arriving).

> Arrive by car
>
> Arrive by train

Arrive at (a place)

> He arrived at his home

Comment: I agree with all of this. I would add that in my opinion, a problem with this sentence is that the word "arrived" brings to my mind the very last step of a journey, while "glacial pace" refers to the entire journey in this case. But I don't have a better word in mind to use in place of "arrived'.

Comment: To amplify this answer, the "at" belongs to the pace, not the arrival of justice.

Comment: @TomB Did I not say that in my second sentence?

Comment: @DavidK: really?  As a native speaker, I found the sentence absolutely fine — I didn’t feel any ambiguity or awkwardness in it at all, and had no idea what the difficulty in it was going to be until I’d read the rest of the question.

Comment: @PLL: Same here, and yet, I agree with David K: I didn't notice the problem myself, but now that it's pointed out, I agree that (for example) "arriving slowly" means that the arrival is slow, not that there's been a long delay before the arrival.

Comment: It still reads fine for me. The court case the text refers to has lasted 7 years! For me thaf means justice was coming, and has **finally** arrived (hence arrivimg at "glacial pace").

Comment: Over twenty years after the war, and seven years after the start of the trial, I would say justice has been a long time _coming._ The pace of _progress_ of the case could be said to have been glacial. Was justice already _arriving_ seven years ago, when the case started? I'm not sure I'd say that. But as I already noted, I don't know how to write the sentence in the question better. Possibly it's just an ambiguity of the language that we have to live with.